# Where did the Unity modal dialogs go?

Tags: unity, compiz, 11.10, plugins, dialog

I'm using Oneric and I was rather impressed by the Unity modal dialog addon. After a few upgrades it was gone. Where did it go? Or is there any way of getting it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been decided that the Unity dialogs are not ready for prime time. They won't ship in Ubuntu 11.10 (see [this changlog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/1:0.9.5.0-0ubuntu2)).